# Add jquery to my "dynamic web project" in eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee

To add my jquery file : 
I created a folder named script (inside the folder "WebContent")
I added the jquery file 
And in the html file  that uses jquery i linked it
And it didn lt work : the page is loaded perfectly in the web browser but the "javascript" part is not working wich is " getting my current position" .
My link is :

Sorry i couldnt upload photos because of a bug

Answer (score 0):

I think u should check linked path of jquery in your file. 
if u use the eclipse, u can check this path whether it linked well with ctrl+click.
and another way, u should clean or refresh your project.